# plotting points on top of image in R

Tags: r, image-processing, plot, scatter-plot

These days I am extensively using R to scatter plots.
Most of the plotting is concerned with image processing,
Recently I was thinking of plotting the scatter plots over an image.

For example, I want something like this,
The background needs to be filled with my image. With a particular scale.
And I should be able to draw points (co-ordinates) on top of this image ...

Is this possible in R?
If not, do you guys know of any other tool that makes this easy ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you have in mind, but I think first you want to load and plot an image in R.  You can do that with the `ReadImages` package:

```
picture <- read.jpeg("avatar.jpg")
plot(picture)
```

Then you can do a scatter plot on top of it:

```
points(runif(50,0, 128), runif(50,0,128))
```

Answer (score 8):

A step-by-step tutorial to this kind of plotting is in the [R-wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3Agraphics-misc%3Atranslucency)

Comment: The link is broken, and while the domain stays and still contains an R wiki, I don't even know which article to look for.

Comment: The link remains (or became again) broken.

Comment: The link is still broken